# Can the outlook-message-parser library handle the UTF-8 characters

Tags: java, msg

I'm using the org.simplejavamail:outlook-message-parser library:

```
        OutlookMessageParser outlookMessageParser = new OutlookMessageParser();
        OutlookMessage outlookMessage = outlookMessageParser.parseMsg("myMessage.msg");
        logger.info(outlookMessage.getBodyText());
```

and output is:

```
Testiviestin sis?lt?
```

The original Outlook message contains this body: "Testiviestin sisältö".

Can the org.simplejavamail:outlook-message-parser library handle the UTF-8 characters?

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem was causing about the logger. It couldn't handle UTF-8 characters.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).